# NPM install giving error installing express

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, npm

When I give command `npm install express` it throws following error. On ubuntu machine

```
gaurav@gaurav-Mini-Monster:~/TestScripts$ sudo npm install -g express
npm ERR! error installing express@3.3.3 Error: Unsupported
npm ERR! error installing express@3.3.3     at checkEngine (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:493:14)
npm ERR! error installing express@3.3.3     at Array.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/bind-actor.js:15:8)
npm ERR! error installing express@3.3.3     at LOOP (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:15:13)
npm ERR! error installing express@3.3.3     at chain (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:20:4)
npm ERR! error installing express@3.3.3     at installOne_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:470:3)
npm ERR! error installing express@3.3.3     at installOne (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:411:3)
npm ERR! error installing express@3.3.3     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:347:9
npm ERR! error installing express@3.3.3     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:54:35
npm ERR! error installing express@3.3.3     at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR! error installing express@3.3.3     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:54:11
npm ERR! error rolling back express@3.3.3 Error: UNKNOWN, Unknown error '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express'
npm ERR! Unsupported
npm ERR! Not compatible with your version of node/npm: connect@2.8.3
npm ERR! Required: {"node":">= 0.8.0"}
npm ERR! Actual:   {"npm":"1.0.106","node":"0.5.11-pre"}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-48-generic-pae
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "express"
npm ERR! cwd /home/gaurav/TestScripts
npm ERR! node -v v0.5.11-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/gaurav/TestScripts/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

I also tried

```
sudo npm install express
npm install -g express
sudo npm install -g express
```

Nothing works.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Node is so easy to install manually. I like doing it this way too because it's really easy to switch versions.

This is also great because you don't need to add some external package repository to `apt`, and you don't have to wait for those repositories to update when node releases a new version. You can get updates as soon as they're released.

```sh
# make a `~/.nodes/ folder
mkdir -p ~/.nodes && cd ~/.nodes

# download the binaries from nodejs.org
# in this case, here's the linux version
curl -O http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.12/node-v0.10.12-linux-x64.tar.gz

# extract
tar -xzf node-v0.10.12-linux-x64.tar.gz

# rename folder to 0.10.12
mv node-v0.10.12-linux-x64 0.10.12

# create a `current` symlink
ln -s 0.10.12 current

# prepend ~/.nodes/bin to your path
# you'll want to save this in ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc or something
export PATH="~/.nodes/current/bin:$PATH"

# cleanup
rm ~/.nodes/node-v0.10.12-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

---

The best part about this is you can repeat the pattern for any other version of node, change the `current` symlink at any time to switch which version you're running, and you're good to go

```sh
% node --version
v0.10.12

% npm --version
1.2.32

# switch versions to (e.g.) 0.10.5
% cd ~/.nodes && rm current && ln -s 0.10.5 current

% node --version
v0.10.5

% npm --version
1.2.18
```

---

Additional pointers when writing executable scripts

Make an executable file

```
% touch ~/somefile && chmod +x ~/someifle && nano ~/somefile
```

File contents

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log(process.version);
```

Run it

```
% ./somefile
v0.10.12
```

Comment: Thanks @naomik. I used same approach of upgrading node using source. Issue solved. Lesson learnt :)

Answer (score 10):

You are running a much-too-old version of `node` and `npm`. You have node v0.5 which is very out of date. Upgrade to node v0.10 and things will work.

Modern node.js versions for Ubuntu are available via [this PPA from Chris Lea](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/)

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like your old version of node is installed at `/usr/local/bin/node`. The new version from the Chris Lea PPA will be at `/usr/bin/node`. So to verify all is well, do:

```
/usr/bin/npm --version #Should be approx 1.2
/usr/bin/node --version #should be approx v0.10
/usr/bin/npm install -g express
```

You should uninstall the local node, or fix your PATH:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I have correctly identified your problem. If you aren't going to put more effort than "It did not work" into helping us help you, you don't deserve our help.

Comment: @PeterLyons at first your comment seemed a bit enraged to me, but I've readed better the question and your answer, and you're completelly correct.

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-software-properties -> this command works well. add-apt-respository command also works well. But sudo apt-get install nodejs executes but still showing me node --version to v0.5.11-pre

Comment: See my update. You have both the old and new versions now and need to be sure to use the new version.