# deploying meteor on my own server

Tags: meteor, web-deployment

I want to deploy my meteor app on my Ubuntu server, I used `meteor.sh` https://github.com/netmute/meteor.sh

and everything went successfully, But i simply can't launch my app from the browser.

I'm putting my ip address and getting a 404 The requested URL / was not found on this server.

I have apache2 running, and i removed its redirection to 8080 (i used it to tomcat before)

Thanks.

(the reason i didn't use meteoric.sh is because i don't have my source code on git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which port are you using? It seems a proper `export PATH=nnnn;` is missing... or maybe you are not including the port number in your browser's address bar, like `http://example.com:1234` for port 1234.

I am in a similar adventure of yours, and [I've just posted the results of my experience here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17620793/370290)!

I didn't use [meteor.sh](https://github.com/netmute/meteor.sh/) nor [meteoric.sh](https://github.com/julien-c/meteoric.sh/), but ended up following their path...

Comment: the meteor.sh is telling me that `Your app is deployed and serving on: http://IP` so i don't think it's a path, and i have my mongodb and node.js. But it might be a port. on what port by default is it on ? or should i specify it ?

Comment: No, no, no... :-) The word "path" there means "way",means "I have not used meteor.sh nor meteoric.sh, but in the end I have done manually almost the same thing that they do "automatically"... I recommend NOT using these scripts, because this is how you can learn how things really work... please read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17620793/370290 - please read the steps **AFTER** Node.JS and MongoDb installations.

Comment: Yes, you need to specify the port. In your server, you need to specify an environment variable named `PORT` with the port number value, like this: `export PORT=3000`. And then, you need to access your server using this port number, in your browser, like this: `http://myserver.com:3000`

Comment: Thank you, and you're right it's much better to do it without the script, it worked! one more thing, how can i make it run indefinitely ?