# I am trying to bundle a meteor app into a .tgz

Tags: git, meteor, bundle, clone, digital-ocean

I am following a tutorial from the discover meteor book, and I am hitting a roadblock. I cloned my project into /home/meteor on my digital ocean ubuntu 13 droplet. The instructions ask me to do the following next.

```
$ cd mymeteorapp 
$ mrt bundle ../bundle.tgz 
$ cd ..
$ tar -zxvf bundle.tgz
```

However after I run the second command mrt bundle ../bundle.tgz I get the following error

```
root@bray:/home/meteor# mrt bundle ../bundle.tgz
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

Not sure why I am getting this error, have been googling around for a while. Any Ideas?

*UPDATE*

Before the instructions above I am asked to install node.js and mongodb, assuming that worked properly. They ask me to do this

git clone https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/microscope.git, in /home/meteor
where the github repository is mine.

Than these instructions, maybe they will explain something I missed and didn't do

The next step is to bundle your app, i.e. generate a fully-contained Node application in a tarball. It is certainly possible to bundle your app in your development environment and then just transmit the tarball, but for now we'd recommend checking out the actual code on the server. This approach has a couple of advantages:

It's Git-based (just specify your project's repository)
It doesn't require you to have Meteor installed locally
It doesn't require re-building packages like Fibers (which are platform-dependent)
And finally, it should allow for hot code fixes (your Node server won't stop when deploying your app)
To bundle and untar our app (note that it would actually be handy for Meteor to be able to "bundle as a directory, not a tarball"), we do:

### -----------

Just realized that node may not be installed at all, I ran node --version and got a weird response

```
root@bray:/home/meteor# node --version
The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
 * node
 * nodejs-legacy
```

### -----------

Comment: It's possible node isn't setup correctly on your server.  Does `meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com` work?

Comment: @portforwardpodcast It attempts to deploy and than gives me a authetication failure, it asked me for a password not sure if I used the right one.

Comment: replace myapp with a unique app name.  If nobody else has used it, you don't need a password

Comment: traditionally people bundle their meteor app on localhost, and then deploy it to the server in some fashion.

Comment: Does this SO post help give you an idea of how to deploy?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606340/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-application-to-my-own-server

Comment: @portforwardpodcast I have added some more info to my post above. The link you provided could help, however I'd like to follow the instructions in the tutorial so I don't get lost.

Comment: @portforwardpodcast I also added something I just checked running node --version gives me a weird result.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so Node wasn't installed for some reason, even though I followed the tutorial instructions. I ended up installing nvm with build-essential and libssl-dev.