# How to get Meteor's routing/instant page change effect, without Meteor?

Tags: jquery, meteor

For those not familiar with the Meteor framework, when you navigate (e.g.) using the top nav, the page changes are almost instantaneous and do not result in the typical page-changing/page-load. Of course you could accomplish this in jQuery using `.load()`, but the thing about Meteor is that you could have a link on some other website to a specific page on your site, such as `http://example.com/about` and Meteor will take you directly to that page. This is good for SEO purposes.

My question:

If I'm not using Meteor, how can I accomplish this instant page-switch effect, *and* have the URL in the address bar change, *and* have each page fully linkable page (not `http://example.com/#about`). If I can keep it as simple as using HTML and jQuery, that would be great.

PS: If the solution involves using Apache or nginx rewrites, I'm okay with that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're building a [single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). The part of an SPA that implements the linking functionality you describe is a "router", and with Meteor you've probably used [iron:router](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router).

What iron:router does is use the [HTML5 pushState() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to manipulate the browser history and URL bar.

If you're new to web app development, you'll probably want a library that does that. You definitely [do not want AngularJS (see why)](http://www.letscodejavascript.com/v3/blog/2015/01/angular_review). However, it turns out that [such no-hashtags routing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395992/single-page-application-router-without-hash-and-small) aren't that common... any reason not to use Meteor with iron:router?

Comment: Oops, and I just ran `yo angular --coffee` to start an Angular web app because I wanted pushState. :)

Comment: PS: Not new to web app development at all.

Comment: Would love to use Meteor, but my server is set up as a typical Apache server. No Node.js.

Comment: Node.js and Apache are orthogonal. BTW, [nginx is for 99% of the cases a much better alternative than Apache.](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/apache_vs_nginx). Can you not [install Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/install)? What are you using for the backend, or are you using [no backend at all](https://unhosted.org)?

Comment: No, I have Meteor on my local Mac, and know how to develop apps with it. Actually, what the issue is is this: I've got a VPS running Apache (it HAS to run it, for now). I know I could probably run a Meteor site on some other port number, and maybe use Apache to reverse proxy to the Node.js port. I just have no clue how :) And no clue how to set up a Node.js server as a Debian service I can control with `sudo service [serviceName] start/stop`. Or I should say, have it start automatically when the server boots up (rc.d script)

Comment: I found this page. This actually helps. Now I just need to figure out how to make node boot my Meteor app up upon system startup. Shouldn't be too hard. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606340/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-application-to-my-own-server

Comment: Does Apache need to server port 80 on the same server? If so, you'll have to proxy_pass somehow. [For nginx, there's a ready-made Meteor config file on Meteorpedia.](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/nginx). Alternatively, a DigitalOcean VPS starts at $5/mo and you can have a clean setup.

Comment: Yes, I've got a mission critical app on port 80 that needs Apache. But yeah, Apache has ProxyPass as well. This should actually be a piece of cake. Thanks for the motivation! :) I was getting into Angular, and *not* really liking it.

Comment: To keep Meteor -> node apps running indefinitely, I used [pm2 instead of forever](http://devo.ps/blog/goodbye-node-forever-hello-pm2/), and there's also [Meteor Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up).