# Meteor app: Intitial loading >1min, 7.4M, 800 requests

Tags: meteor

I have a relatively simple meteor.js app. It loads crazy slow (>1min) and downloads 7.4M of resources.

At first I thought this is due to slow subscriptions but the network log shows that it is actually caused by the resource downloads (>800 requests).

I also realized that most entries show up twice in the network log. Is this normal behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar concern when I was developing my first meteor app. However, when I created a bundle and deployed the app (which is the way you are supposed to do it in production) all the resources are minified, compressed, and compiled into a couple of resources.

The diffefence between a properly deployed production bundle and running your app in dev via the `meteor` command is night and day.

Check this answer on how to bundle and deploy meteor properly. It's in the second half of the top answer:

[How to deploy a meteor application to my own server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606340/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-application-to-my-own-server)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It is actually sufficient to add the --production argument to the meteor call. It now loads in 3.6s with 1.5M and 29 requests... much better :)