# node.js 0.10.17 error installation test (AssertionError)

Tags: node.js

```
Command: out/Release/node /Users/akhyar/Documents/node/node-master/test/simple/test-memory-usage-emfile.js
=== release test-tls-server-verify ===                                         
Path: simple/test-tls-server-verify
connecting with agent1
  connecting with agent2
  connecting with agent3
  connecting with nocert
  connecting with agent1
Running 'Do not request certs. Everyone is unauthorized.'
- unauthed connection: null
  * unauthed
- unauthed connection: null
  * unauthed
- unauthed connection: null
  * unauthed
- unauthed connection: null
  * unauthed
Running 'Allow both authed and unauthed connections with CA1'

assert.js:92
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: agent1 rejected, but should NOT have been
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/akhyar/Documents/node/node-master/test/simple/test-tls-server-verify.js:217:14)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:790:12)
Command: out/Release/node /Users/akhyar/Documents/node/node-master/test/simple/test-tls-server-verify.js
[02:17|% 100|+ 633|-   3]: Done                                                
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

I dont know why this error happen. Is node.js 0.10.17 stable version? 
I got that error when instaling node.js on macosx mountain lion 10.8.4
Can anyone give a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0.10.17` is current and stable

I've [written this up before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474687/npm-install-giving-error-installing-express/17475923#17475923) so I won't write it all again.

**Summary:** node.js is extremely simple to install manually

```sh
# make a `~/.nodes/ folder
mkdir -p ~/.nodes && cd ~/.nodes

# download the binaries from nodejs.org
# in this case, here's the linux version
curl -O http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.17/node-v0.10.17-darwin-x64.tar.gz

# extract
tar -xzf node-v0.10.17-darwin-x64.tar.gz

# rename folder to 0.10.17
mv node-v0.10.17-darwin-x64 0.10.17

# create a `current` symlink
ln -s 0.10.17 current

# prepend ~/.nodes/bin to your path
# you'll want to save this in ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc or something
export PATH="~/.nodes/current/bin:$PATH"

# cleanup
rm ~/.nodes/node-v0.10.17-darwin-x64.tar.gz
```