# Node js can't require modules installed globally in OS X

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I installed module by

```
sudo npm install -g xxx
```

in OS X, and the command echoes the module was installed in 
`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/xxx`.

But the require('xxx') still fails claiming `Cannot find module 'xxx'. Only installing the module locally again by

```
sudo npm install xxx
```

can fix the error.

Anything need to be configured in my OSX?

Comment: I don't know how you installed node, but I installed it [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474687/npm-install-giving-error-installing-express/17475923#17475923) on OSX and I haven't had any issues with it. Also, I don't have to use `sudo` to install stuff, which is nice.

Comment: I used **homebrew** to install **node** and **npm**, and I don't know why if I didn't install stuff with `sudo`, the **EACCESS** error will occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in one of your startup files (most likely `~/.bash_profile`):

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH
```

Start a new shell and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think if globally you need the absolute paths:

`var xxx = require("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/xxx");`

> If you want to load a local, relative Javascript module into a Node.js
>   application, you can simply use the require() method in conjunction
>   with relative (or absolute) file paths:

```
var moduleA = require( "./module-a.js" );
var moduleB = require( "../../module-b.js" );
var moduleC = require( "/my-library/module-c.js" );
```

from http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm